# GUI issue, touching "button2" executes "button1" action on some devices

Tags: android, user-interface

I have the following layout in my application, which minimal API level is 4 and targets API level 8. The fact is that in some devices such as Xperia X10 mini, when I touch @+actBula/btnZoomOut, the action taken is from the button on its side @+actBula/btnZoomIn. Whereas in Xperia X8 and another Samsung phones it works great.

Specifications of Xperia X10 mini are 240 x 320 pixels, 2.55 inches (~157 ppi pixel density).
Xperia X8 are 320 x 480 pixels, 3.0 inches (~192 ppi pixel density).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="left">
        <Button android:id="@+actBula/btnBack" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:background="@drawable/setabola48" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="right" android:layout_gravity="right" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">
        <Button android:id="@+actBula/btnZoomIn" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/zoomp48" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+actBula/btnZoomOut" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:background="@drawable/zoomm48" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></Button>          
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" (...) ></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

These are the onClick listeners:

```
    final TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.actBula.txtBula);

    Button btnZoomIn = (Button) findViewById(R.actBula.btnZoomIn);

    btnZoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          myTextView.setTextSize(myTextView.getTextSize()+1);
        }
    });

    Button btnZoomOut = (Button) findViewById(R.actBula.btnZoomOut);

    btnZoomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          myTextView.setTextSize(myTextView.getTextSize()-1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you add the `onClick` listeners? Also, have you tried logging the actual method calls when the buttons are pressed to make sure it isn't a simple logic error?

Comment: I did not log, but since the same apk and xml layout works differently on different devices my guess is that it's a pixel density matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem by changing this line:  `myTextView.setTextSize(myTextView.getTextSize()-1);` into `myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, myTextView.getTextSize()-1);`

getTextSize() returns the exact pixel size. If I specify my unit I get the desired result.
Thanks for whoever helped me here.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the id's of the buttons are mixed up in R.java. Have you run `Clean...` before uploading your app to Xperia X10 mini?

It's unlikely due to Android 1.6, but try changing temporarily the target API level to 4 to run the app at Xperia X10 mini and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've run Project>Clean before compiling. In fact, the app was downloaded direct from Android Market on both phones, so it was the same apk. I tested on my friend's X10 mini, when I get through him again I'll test it.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try declaring the buttons with id's placed to the standard location. I mean, change `"@+actBula/btnZoomIn"` to `"@+id/btnZoomIn"` and so on.

One more thing to clarify is the actual id's which the buttons get. Add some printout to your code and see the buttons id's LogCat will print:

```
final TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.actBula.txtBula);

Button btnZoomIn = (Button) findViewById(R.actBula.btnZoomIn);

//That's what I added:
Log.i("", "btnZoomIn.getId()=" + btnZoomIn.getId() + ", R.actBula.btnZoomIn=" + R.actBula.btnZoomIn);

btnZoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      myTextView.setTextSize(myTextView.getTextSize()+1);
    }
});

Button btnZoomOut = (Button) findViewById(R.actBula.btnZoomOut);

//That's what I added:
Log.i("", "btnZoomOut.getId()=" + btnZoomOut.getId() + ", R.actBula.btnZoomOut=" + R.actBula.btnZoomOut);

btnZoomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      myTextView.setTextSize(myTextView.getTextSize()-1);
    }
});
```

Comment: I logged like you stated and buttons id matched. I tried a different screen size for the emulator and now I have a clearer understanding of the problem. In this image: http://imageshack.us/f/708/myscreenw.png/ the zoom out button shrinks and regardless of clicking on zoom out, it zooms in. That's something to do about layout.